# how can I hide tail triangle on popup

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

[image http://pasteio.com/m26f642c81452a5bf67cfc5f0b0f2390c](http://pasteio.com/m26f642c81452a5bf67cfc5f0b0f2390c)

I'm using leaflet to render the mapbox map. There is small triangle on the top of marker; how can I hide it?

Comment: can you provide us with the code as well as a example of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This triangle is controlled by the `.leaflet-popup-tip` class in css. If you are using standard Leaflet, you should be able to hide the tip by adding the following to your css (after `leaflet.css` is loaded):

```
.leaflet-popup-tip {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
```

Mapbox actually creates the tip in a slightly different way from standard Leaflet, by styling the element border rather than the element content, so if you are using `mapbox.js`, you should be able to do it by adding the following (after `mapbox.css` is loaded):

```
.leaflet-popup-tip {
    border: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: I did add on my CSS file but it doens't work, checkout here: http://kiwich.com/dev/index.php/index/map

Comment: Hmm... that page is actually not showing me any map at all, as it fails on line 97 of `kiwich-map.js` with the error `Cannot read property 'lat' of null`. I don't know exactly what is causing that, but my guess would be some issue with the API. However, I realized that Mapbox creates the tip in a different way from standard Leaflet, so i have updated may answer with a solution for `mapbox.js` as well.

Answer (score 14):

For others coming across this post who may be struggling with the tooltip triangle, or even the background css of the tooltip, I have put together my research in one place and found the various ways to affect the triangle and the background of the tooltips and the popups!

If you have a POPUP bound to a marker, `.leaflet-popup-tip` controls the triangle. Here I am hiding it:

```
.leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

If you have a TOOLTIP you have added to the map, you can control the tooltip's triangle with this magical css:

```
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before, 
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before, 
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before, 
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
    border: none !important;
}
```

More styling:
POPUP: You can also control the popup's css as well by targeting `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper`. Here I am completely removing all traces of the background/border/box of the popup & enlarging the font:

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

TOOLTIP: You can add a class name to a tooltip when you create it such as `{className: 'popup'}`, and then use that to style the tooltip:

```
.popup {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

To see how to add tooltips and popups to the map, and how all of this works together, here is a working example with commenting throughout:
https://repl.it/@MeowMeow/NeighboringConventionalPhp

Hope this is helpful to someone! :)